# Scala function requires Symbol/Any instate Array/Sequence

Tags: scala, playframework

I should use a function for a scala function parameter. The function looks like this:

```
def apply(field: Field, options: Seq[(String, String)], args: (Symbol, Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: Lang): Html
```

The `args` param takes arrays like:

```
'_label -> "mylabel", '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control"
```

In the play framework it looks like this:

```
@helper.select(myForm("fieldName"), options = options(MyObject.options), '_label -> "mylabel", '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control")
```

How do I correctly write a method which adds an item to the array? Something like this:

```
@helper.select(callForm("callee"), options = options(LineDimension.options), args('_label -> "mylabel", '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control"))
```

The function:

```
@args(args: (Symbol, Any)*) = @{
    if (!filterEnabled) {
        args.add('disabled -> "disabled")
    }
    args
}
```

The error message from the play console is:

```
... type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[(Symbol, Any)]
[error]  required: (Symbol, Any)
[error]             @helper.select(callForm("callee"), options = options(LineDimension.options), args('_label -> Messages.get("call.callee.choose"), '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control"))
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar to this. Where does the @args function go? Should it be in my view or my controller? Also, what does the `'disabled -> "disabled"` part do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `args(...): _*`

```
@helper.select(callForm("callee"), options = options(LineDimension.options), args('_label -> Messages.get("call.callee.choose"), '_showConstraints -> false, 'class -> "form-control"): _*)
```

**EDIT**:

```
@args(args: (Symbol, Any)*) = @{
  if (!filterEnabled) {
    args :+ ('disabled -> "disabled")
  } else args
}
```

Then use like I mentioned above.

Comment: That helped but I had to add an array declaration `@args(args: Array[(Symbol, Any)]) = @{`. How can I add now an element to the array? Something like `args + 'disabled -> "disabled"`. With this it complains: type mismatch, found Symbol, required String